# XPath to get parents with multiple children but only one type of child

Tags: xpath

I need an XPath (1.0) to get all parent nodes with multiple children but only one type of child (e.g., either `<div>` or `<li>` but not `<div>` and `<li>`). Any help? Thank you!

```
<doc>
    <tom>
        <janet />
    </tom>
    <dick>
        <janet />
        <jane />
    </dick>
    <harry>
        <jane />
    </harry>
</doc>
```

So for the above we should get tom and harry but not dick

Comment: an example would be very helpful ;-)

Comment: I am not sure that an example would be particularly helpful for this question, because it addresses in general if there is a way to check whether child elements are all of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example as a reference, the following XPath 1.0 expression:

`/doc/*[count(./*) = count(./*[name(.) = name(../*[1])])]`

Will return all children of `doc` where the total number of children of that element equals the number of children with the same name as the first child of that element.  Or, more simply put, all children have the same name aka 'type'.

However, the above will return nodes that have 0 or 1 children, so to restrict it to only those where there are multiple child nodes, we can use:
`/doc/*[count(./*) = count(./*[name(.) = name(../*[1])]) and count(./*) > 1]`

If you want to further restrict it so that all children have to be a certain element, for example `jane`, you could use: `/doc/*[count(./*) = count(./*[name(.) = name(../*[1])]) and count(./*) > 1 and ./*[1] = ./jane[1]]`

Comment: Very clever solution, thank you! I suppose `//*[count(./*) = count(./*[name(.) = name(../*[1])]) and count(./*) > 1]` can be considered as the solution for this problem if there is no further restriction to the path.